# How to layer via cut/copy multiple selections (from 1 layer)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

How can I "layer via cut/copy" multiple selections from one layer at the same time. These selections are all different shapes and all on the same image. I have no problem making the selection one by one so the selection is not the problem.

Is there a short cut where I can just "layer via cut/copy" all selections, to their own individual layer, all at once at the end? It would save me a lot of time!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

How would the software be able to tell which selection areas should be sent to separate or the same layer? I don't think it's that smart.

Instead, you could try selecting everything you want to cut to other layers, and then deselect each part which you want to leave on the current layer, and cut to a new layer the rest until you've cut up everything into separate layers.

This at least saves you the time re-selecting everything each time from the same layer.

Comment: But is there no way of splitting every single selection into a new layer at once? Even if it's one pixel selected by accident that becomes a new layer, I can weed those out after. I also don't need to group any selections to a single layer, I need them all individually, I understand it would be hard if I needed something more specific. Thanks for your help!